# Updating elements of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, element, updates

I'm seeking to update a team results array below.  The football score will populate positions 1 and 2 of each inner array.

```
var teamResults=[
  ["Home","F","A","Away"],
  ["A",,,"B"],
  ["A",,,"C"],
  ["B",,,"C"],
  ["B",,,"A"],
  ["C",,,"A"],
  ["C",,,"B"],
];
```

Initially each score is undefined as below:

```
console.log(teamResults[1]);

 ["A" ,undefined ,undefined ,"B"]
```

Using 'splice' works to update team A's score in fixture #1:

```
teamResults[1].splice(1,1,3);

["A" ,3 ,undefined ,"B"]
```

However, using the same method for team B fails.  It overwrites Teams A's score and the element for Team B's score disappears completely?

```
teamResults[1].splice(1,2,4); 

["A" ,4 ,"B"]
```

Any advice on how to produce the following array would be greatly appreciated

```
["A" ,3 ,4 ,"B"]
```

Comment: Just do teamResults[1][1] = 3 and teamResults[1][2] = 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not assign the value with the index, without splicing.

```
teamResults[1][1] = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you - that's brilliantly simple! And I can access all fixtures in the array in this way?

Comment: Yes, you can! ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) syntax is:

> var arrDeletedItems = array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])

So `teamResults[1].splice(1,2,4);` will remove 2 element from index 1 and then add 4.

In your case it should be `teamResults[1].splice(2,1,4);`

```js
var arr = ["A" ,3 ,undefined ,"B"];

arr.splice(2, 1, 4);

console.log(arr)
```